# how to toggle multiple inputs within a table depending on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

**Assume the following html:**

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="c1_testRdio">Have you taken any tests in this class?:</label>
        <br>
        <label>Yes<input type="radio" class="testRdio" name="c1_testRdio" value="Yes"></label>
        <label>No <input type="radio" class="testRdio" name="c1_testRdio" value="No" checked></label>
        <label>How Many? <input type="text" class="howManyTests" name="c1_howManyTests" disabled></label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label for="c1_whatGradesTests">What were your grades?:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="c1_whatGradesTests" disabled>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**if radio with `value="Yes"` is selected, what jQuery (1.5 compatible ) code would enable the 2 text inputs, `c1_howManyTests` and `c1_whatGradesTests`**?

*Have tried:*

```
$('.testRdio').change(function(){
    //var txt = $(this).closest("td").next("td").children('.howManyTests');
    var txt = $(this).parent().next('label>input[type="text"]');
    console.log(txt.id);
    this.value == 'No' ? txt.removeAttr('disabled') : txt.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Comment: create the radio buttons with a display of none (remove from dom), and then use jquery to see if('cq_testRdio') is selected then change the css of the radio  buttons to display (you can use slidetoggle for animation)

Comment: You're missing a `">`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: good eye, but it's actually there in the code. Accidentally lost in the copy/paste, so not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.testRdio').change(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]').attr('disabled', this.value === 'No');
});
```

The older jq version that doesnot have prop, `attr` (used to do the job of prop as well) used to take bool values for disabled.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LtcwB/)**

*Also i had to fix your markup a lot as well (Now i see its fixed in the question already)*

Comment: works Perfect. Will accept best answer in few minutes. What was wrong with the markup if I may ask?

Comment: @Prefix no your initial markup, just now saw that you updated ur question fixing the markup.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.testRdio').change(function(){
   $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]').attr('disabled',$(this).val()=="No");
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Tj4Za/2)**

Comment: good answer, unfortunately not jQuery 1.5 compatible like requested.

Comment: also this woul dchange all the text inputs on the page. I want to change ONLY the 2 provided in the original post.

Comment: Updated to be 1.5 compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Your code was a little messy, so I rebuilt it: http://jsfiddle.net/QgJac/1/

I think hiding the whole `div` is better. They don't really need to see those questions if they select 'No'.

Comment: hiding the whole div isn't desirable in this situation. Solid code though, cheers.